# Moving one object causes other to move another (already tried unlinking)

Tags: modeling

Problem:

I have situation like this:

[image]
http://postimg.org/image/7vjo0zbzt/f70ae78b/

When I move The highlithed object the green human object moves its component as well and it shoudln't.

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/n4xo6j23r/f63b3af1/

Objects are in no parent-child relationship.

Linked - maybe?

I thought that object may be linked. SO I tried unliking:
- I highlithed the object (but not green human)
- I pressed U --> Object
- Is that all you have to do to unlink objects?

Can you point me in what I am doing wrong?

Side question: How can I check if an object is linked with another object?

Answer (score 24):

I had proportional editing on.

If you ever think your objects are acting as though they were linked and they aren't be sure to check if you haven't by mistake turned on proportional editing. Otherwise you may end up with situation like the one described above.

[image: 3D view header with proportional editing button highlighted]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Not sure how I turned that on so I had no idea what the heck was going on as I moved things. This fixed it for me.

Comment: On my setup, it was at the top of the screen.

Comment: THANKS! Blender is such a powerful but insanely confusing program!